# Redirect URL before checking for ssl certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssl

I have a rails application deployed on aws.  We recently switched domains and need to redirect to the new domain.  We got a new SSL certificate and installed it on aws for the new domain.  The redirect using route 53 works when I added the cname record.  The only issue is when someone goes to www.oldsite.com it says invalid SSL cert and asks if the user wants to continue to unsafe site.  If they select yes then it redirects properly to https://www.newsite.com.  How do we make it so the warning message doesn't come for www.oldsite.com?

Here's the code I added in routes.rb file

```
constraints(:host => /oldsite.com/) do
    match '/(*path)' => redirect { |params, req|
      query_params = req.params.except(:path)
      "http://newsite.com/#{params[:path]}#{query_params.keys.any? ? "?" + query_params.to_query : ""}"
    }, via: [:get, :post]
  end
```

Comment: You can't get rid of that warning message without serving a valid SSL certificate for your old domain.

Comment: Is there a way on aws to allow multiple certs for the Elastic Beanstalk instance?  In the aws console I went to my beanstalk instance -> configuration -> load balancing -> SSL certificate ID and selected (Optional) Select a Certificate from the drop down list.    I then got this errror "SSLCertificateId: Invalid option value: 'aws:elb:listener:443' (Namespace: 'aws:elb:listener:443', OptionName: 'SSLCertificateId'): Invalid SSL Certificate Id: ARNs must start with 'arn:':"

Comment: Or...is there a way to redirect without the server checking for a valid certificate?

Comment: *Or...is there a way to redirect without the server checking for a valid certificate?*  Isn't it the *user* that's getting the "invalid SSL cert" error?

Comment: The server isn't checking for a valid certificate, the **browser** is checking.

Comment: A cheap way to solve this would be to point the old domain to an ec2.nano instance that is doing nothing but running Nginx serving redirect requests and a valid certificate. Another cheap way to solve it would be to move the old domain to CloudFlare with a free SSL certificate and redirect using a page rule.

Comment: Or CloudFront for SSL backed by S3 to issue the redirect.